# Optimizing Google Search Results: Enhancing Visibility and Content Presentation

Tags: search, seo

I’ve got a few questions on how to update Google’s Search Results:

1. When you Google “Lightwell Architecture”, the first result is the “About Us Page” instead of the “Home Page”. How do I change this priority?
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpVJ.png)
2. You’ll notice that the text, “- Header” is in the title as well. How do I update this? Is it just a matter of updating the  element?
3. How do you get Google to add other links like so?
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MuCz.png)

I’m assuming I’ll need access to Google Search Console for these updates, but would love some instructions/tips/advice.

Thanks in advance!

So far, I’ve tried looking through Google’s SEO tips.

Comment: Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se].  Each question you have should be asked in a separate post.  Some of your questions are already answered there like [Showing the home page first in Google search results for searches for the domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111836/showing-the-home-page-first-in-google-search-results-for-searches-for-the-domain/111847?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C17.6972#111847)

Comment: and [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)